# plotting subplots with a shared slider in python

Tags: python, plotly, slider, subplot, shared

I am trying to plot 3 subplots (separate scatter plots directly one under the other with a separate slider underneath them that controls them all) that share the same x range data with a slider that controls all of them on the bottom.
I have managed to do that with one plot but I do not know how to add the other 2 subplots. I am sharing the code with a small part of the dataseries.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # pandas series, string
y1=[90, 92, 89, 82, 82, 78, 76, 82, 85, 88] # pandas series, numpy int64
y2=[20, 21, 19, 20, 18, 17, 14, 16, 18, 23] # pandas series, numpy int64
y3=[40, 42, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 49, 45, 46] # pandas series, numpy int64


fig1 = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)
fig2 = px.scatter(x=x,y=y1,labels = dict(x = "time",y = "var"))
fig1 = go.Figure(data = fig2.data) # this is defined like that so I can add a second dataset on the same plot if needed, but I need y2,y3 on a separate plot
fig1.update_layout(yaxis_title='var',xaxis_title='time')
fig1.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)
fig1.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create 3 separate subplots (one above the other) that share the same x range data with a slider that controls all of them, what we can do is we can  created 3 traces (one for each subplot) and added them to the subplots with the appropriate row and column values. The rangeslider_visible=True option is set to enable the range slider for the x-axis, which will control all 3 subplots. I hope This Helps.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1 = [90, 92, 89, 82, 82, 78, 76, 82, 85, 88]
y2 = [20, 21, 19, 20, 18, 17, 14, 16, 18, 23]
y3 = [40, 42, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 49, 45, 46]

#Adding the traces for each subplot
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)
trace1 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1, mode='lines', name='Trace 1')
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2, mode='lines', name='Trace 2')
trace3 = go.Scatter(x=x, y=y3, mode='lines', name='Trace 3')

#Add the traces to the subplots
fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace2, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace3, row=3, col=1)

#Setting titles and labels
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='Time', row=3, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Var', row=2, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True) #Added a range slider to control all subplots
fig.show() #Showing the Figure
```

Comment: thank you, when I used this my plots show lines, is it possible to show scatterplots and not show data on the actual slider?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to show scatterplots and not show data on the actual slider in Plotly. You can do this by customizing the range slider using the rangeslider attribute and setting the visible property to False for the slider's data.

Here is Code Sample : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1obXe-sOVpdPSDvcSeMPX9sVaW6yo2gLX?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Is your intended graph that you want to control the three subputs with a single range slider? If so, you can add each graph in the graph object and display the range slider at the bottom, which you can control since the x-axis is shared.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y3,), row=3, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=False, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=False, row=2, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True, row=3, col=1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, is it possible for the plot to be a scatterplot instead of the line and remove the data that is on the slider?

Comment: Line graphs can be changed to scatter plots, but range slider data cannot be deleted. What is the reason for wanting to delete it?

Comment: it is easier to use the slider when there is no data on it, and it gives a little more flexibility in how you zoom in the data. My example code has the slider without the data on them, but I just could not make it work with the subplots. Maybe because I used the plotly.express?

Comment: My guess is that the range slider is basically designed to provide interactive functionality on a single graph. Therefore, I think that erasing the data negates its original purpose. I also don't think the reason it doesn't work is that you are using express.